# Scroll view delegate methods app is crashing in iPAD 1st generation

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

My scenario is when scrollview moving horizontally it has to show one question with table view and with some controls inside table view..

When moving scrollview horizontally i am releasing previous tables and labels and creating new tables and new labels.

But my app is crashing after scrolling some 20 times i.e., in device only but working fine in simulator.

I run app with instruments there are no leaks..

My doubt is that is there any problem with this iPAD 1st generation RAM means not sufficient or any other problem..
Here is my code..

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
@try {

cancelScroll = NO;

if (scrollEnabled) {

scrollEnabled = NO;
NSLog(@"Begin Scroll Dragging");
NSLog(@"%f -- %f",scrollView.contentOffset.x,scrollView.contentOffset.y);

if (scrollDirection == 1) {

    scrollDirection = 0;
    rect = mainTable.frame;
    [scrollTableView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:NO];
    return;
}

else if (scrollDirection == 2) {

    scrollDirection = 0;
    HUDProgress.alpha=0;

    pageWidth = scrollTableView.frame.size.width;
    if (pageControlBeingUsed) {

        page = pageControl.currentPage;

    }

    else {

        page= floor((scrollTableView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    }

    NSLog(@"%d",page);

    if (page == [questionTextArray count] - 1) {

        if (maxValueReached) {

            rect = mainTable.frame;
            [scrollTableView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:NO];
            return;
        }

    }

    photoAlbumView.alpha = 0;
    photoView.alpha = 0;
    FileAddView.alpha = 0;
    settingsView.alpha = 0;
    refreshView.alpha = 0;

    photoAlbumViewPortrait.alpha = 0;
    FileAddViewPortrait.alpha = 0;
    settingsViewPortrait.alpha = 0;
    refreshViewPortrait.alpha = 0;

    checkValueForTableView = TRUE;


    if (orientation == 1 ) {

        if (!expandAction) {

            scrollTableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([questionTextArray count] * 720.0, 596.0);

        }
        else {

            scrollTableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([questionTextArray count] * 930.0, 596.0);

        }
    }
    else {
        if (!expandAction) {

            scrollTableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([questionTextArray count] * 520.0, 680.0);

        }
        else {

            scrollTableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([questionTextArray count] * 720.0, 680.0);

        }

    }


    if (page >= 0) {

        if (page > tempPage) {

             difference = page - tempPage;

            NSLog(@"%d",difference);
            NSLog(@"%f",tableXPosition);

            tableXPosition =  (tableXPosition  + (difference * tableWidthPosition));
            NSLog(@"%f",tableXPosition);
        }

        else if (page < tempPage){

             difference = tempPage - page;

            NSLog(@"%d",difference);

            tableXPosition = abs ((difference * tableWidthPosition) - tableXPosition);

            NSLog(@"%f",tableXPosition);

        }

        else {

            rect = mainTable.frame;
            [scrollTableView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:NO];

        }

    }

    if([questionTextArray count] > 1)
    {
        pageControl.numberOfPages = [questionTextArray count];

        [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        if(scrollTableView != nil)
        {
            if (mainTable != nil) {

         //       mainTable.delegate = nil;
                [mainTable release];
                mainTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tableXPosition , 45.0, tableWidthPosition, 565.0) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
            }

            mainTable.delegate = self;
            mainTable.dataSource = self;
            mainTable.scrollEnabled = YES;
            mainTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [mainTable reloadData];
            [scrollTableView addSubview:mainTable];

        }

        NSLog(@"%d  %d",page,previousPage);

        if (page >= 0) {

            if (previousPage != page) {

                pageControl.currentPage= page;
            }
        }


        if (page >= 0) {

            if (previousPage != page) {

                UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
                UILabel *questionTextLbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
                UILabel *questionNumberLbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];

                if (orientation == 1) {
                      if (!expandAction) {

                        imgView.frame = CGRectMake(tableXPosition, 0.0, 710.0, 39.0);
                        questionTextLbl1.frame =  CGRectMake(10.0, 2.0, 430.0, 35.0);
                        questionNumberLbl1.frame = CGRectMake(550.0, 2.0, 200.0, 35.0);
                    }
                    else {

                        imgView.frame = CGRectMake(tableXPosition, 0.0, 920.0, 39.0);
                        questionTextLbl1.frame =  CGRectMake(50.0, 2.0, 500.0, 35.0);
                        questionNumberLbl1.frame = CGRectMake(800.0, 2.0, 150.0, 35.0);

                        compressButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                        compressButton.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 25.0, 25.0);
                        [compressButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Drop Down small2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        [compressButton addTarget:self action:@selector(compressAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


                    }


                    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
                    imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Top gary header.png"];
                    [scrollTableView addSubview:imgView];

                    if (!expandAction) {

                        NSLog(@"expandAction"); 
                    }
                    else {
                        compressButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                        [compressButton addTarget:self action:@selector(compressAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                      [imgView addSubview:compressButton];
                        imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

                    }

                    questionTextLbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    questionTextLbl1.numberOfLines = 0;
                    questionTextLbl1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.%@?",page + 1,[questionTextArray objectAtIndex:page]];
                    NSLog(@"Question arry %@", questionTextArray);
                    [imgView addSubview:questionTextLbl1];

                    if([questionTextArray count] > 1)
                    {
                        questionNumberLbl1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Question %d/%d",page + 1,[questionTextArray count]];

                    }
                    else {
                        questionNumberLbl1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Question 1"];
                    }

                    questionNumberLbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    questionNumberLbl1.numberOfLines = 0;
                    [imgView addSubview:questionNumberLbl1];
                }

                else {

                    if (!expandAction) {

                        imgView.frame = CGRectMake(tableXPosition, 0.0, 530.0, 38.0);
                        questionTextLbl1.frame =  CGRectMake(10.0, 2.0, 350.0, 35.0);
                        questionNumberLbl1.frame = CGRectMake(380.0, 2.0, 150.0, 35.0);
                    }
                    else {
                        imgView.frame = CGRectMake(tableXPosition, 0.0, 720.0, 38.0);
                        questionTextLbl1.frame =  CGRectMake(40.0, 2.0, 500.0, 35.0);
                        questionNumberLbl1.frame = CGRectMake(550.0, 2.0, 150.0, 35.0);

                        compressButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                        compressButton.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 25.0, 25.0);
                        [compressButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Drop Down small2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        [compressButton addTarget:self action:@selector(compressAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                    }

                    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
                    imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Top gary header.png"];
                    [scrollTableView addSubview:imgView];

                    if (!expandAction) {

                        NSLog(@"expandAction");
                    }
                    else {
                    [imgView addSubview:compressButton];
                    imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

                    }


                    questionTextLbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    questionTextLbl1.numberOfLines = 0;
                    questionTextLbl1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
                    questionTextLbl1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.%@?",page + 1,[questionTextArray objectAtIndex:page]];
                    NSLog(@"Question arry %@", questionTextArray);
                    [imgView addSubview:questionTextLbl1];

                    if([questionTextArray count] > 1)
                    {
                        questionNumberLbl1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Question %d/%d",page + 1,[questionTextArray count]];

                    }
                    else {
                        questionNumberLbl1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Question 1"];
                    }

                    questionNumberLbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    questionNumberLbl1.numberOfLines = 0;
                    [imgView addSubview:questionNumberLbl1];

        }

                [mainTable reloadData];
           //     [scrollTableView  addSubview:mainTable];


                rect = mainTable.frame;

                if (pageControlBeingUsed) {

                    [scrollTableView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:YES];
                    pageControlBeingUsed = NO;

                }

                else {

                    [scrollTableView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:NO];
                }

                tempPage = page;
                previousPage = page;

                if (page == [questionTextArray count] - 1){

                    maxValueReached = YES;
                }

                else {

                    maxValueReached = NO;
                }

                [imgView release];
                [questionNumberLbl1 release];
                [questionTextLbl1 release];

            }

        }

        NSLog(@"page:%d  previous page:%d temp page:%d",page,previousPage,tempPage);

    }

}

}

else {

    [self killScroll];
    scrollDirection = 0;

}

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {

    NSLog(@"Exception: %@---%@",[exception name],[exception reason]);
}
@finally {

    NSLog(@"Finally block");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My doubt is that is there any problem with this iPAD 1st generation RAM means not sufficient or any other problem.

Your intuition about memory is correct, IMO. Your method is really hard to follow, so I am not sure but it seems that you are instantiating a log of views and label and adding them to your main scrollTableView, but never removing them. That could explain the memory fill-up.

Take `imgView`, you instantiate it:

```
     UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
```

add it to `scrollTableView`:

```
 [scrollTableView addSubview:imgView];
```

add several subviews to `imgView`:

```
 [imgView addSubview:questionTextLbl1];
 [imgView addSubview:questionNumberLbl1];
```

you release it correctly:

```
[imgView release];
```

but I cannot see any place where you remove `imgView` from `scrollTableView` before adding a new `imgView` to it... so you just keep adding `imgView` on top of `imgView`...

A simple way to check whether what I am saying is true is adding this statement to `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`:

```
      NSLog(@"LOGGING NUMBER OF SUBVIEWS: %d", [scrollTableView.subviews count]);
```

e.g.,

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  @try {

   cancelScroll = NO;
   if (scrollEnabled) {
      NSLog(@"LOGGING NUMBER OF SUBVIEWS: %d", [scrollTableView.subviews count]);
      ...
```

and you will se that each time that you scroll, the number of subviews will increase.

Comment: No,Every time frame for table view and frame for image view changes..So,it will not overlap..Some other problem is there i think...

Comment: yeah, no overlap, but the problem is not that the views overlap: the problem is that all the views stay there all the time... you should remove the views when they are not needed anymore, otherwise they will continue staying in memory...

Comment: Please, see my edit, if you want to check how many view are contained in your scrollTableView at any time...